# Referral table structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I need to make a simple referral system and I have a database table set out as follows:

```
mem_id | date | refer_email | accepted
```

And the meaning of such columns is the following:

- `mem_id`: The member unique identifier who is making the referral.
- `date`: The timestamp value of the request.
- `refer_email`: The contact email address owned by the person being referred.
- `accepted`: A CHAR value of `Y` or `N` that indicates if the referred `person` received acceptance.

I am not sure if this is best structure for this kind of scenario. I will be required to tally the `number_of_users` referred by each `person` mainly, and I expect a few more simple queries on the horizon.

Comment: So when `accepted` is `Y`, the referred person has been accepted. What does it mean when it is `N`? Rejected? Would there be a need to represent if a referred person has neither been accepted nor rejected?

Comment: There is a user table as well, I shall post it. Yes if the referral is rejected I would like to keep track of that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the following to that schema:

`refer_mem_id` - The member unique identifier of the person who has accepted the referral.

Remove the `accepted` column, the value in `refer_mem_id` gives you this information.

Comment: I see, so I would update this column after the person has registered in this case?

Comment: @kabuto178 Yes that is correct